# PHP function universal database query

Tags: php, database, oracle, function

There are few places in the code where there is a 6-8 queries to the database, queries, various (select, insert, update, procedure call)
can't merge all queries in one, I quickly wrote function code was similar to what is necessary, but the function itself does not look good.
And yet, also need the ability to attach to the request several variables.

Perhaps someone, has something like that or help me to correct this function.

UPDATE: problem has been solved.

```
function execSql($conn,$xsql,$sql_no,$return_val,
                      $binding_val_name,$binding_val,
                       $bind_additional1,$bind_additional2){

    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $xsql);
    if($binding_val_name !='')
      if($bind_additional1)
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name,
                          $binding_val,$bind_additional1,$bind_additional2);
      else
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name, $binding_val);

    oci_execute($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
    if($return_val!='')
      oci_fetch_all($stmt,$result);

    checkError($stmt,$sql_no.'. '.$xsql);
    oci_free_statement($stmt);

    if($return_val!=''&&$return_val!='1')
      return $result[$return_val][0];
    if($binding_val_name!='')
      return $binding_val;
  }
```

and examples of calls

```
$doc = execSql($conn, $sql,'2', '',':doc','',8, SQLT_INT);
$reg_key = execSql($conn, $select,'3', 'REG_KEY',':doc',$doc);
```

using arrays

```
    if($binding_val_name !='')
          if(is_array($binding_val))
            if($bind_additional1[0])
              for ($i=0; $i < count($bind_additional1) ; $i++) { 
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name[$i],
 $binding_val[$i],$bind_additional1[$i],$bind_additional2[$i]);.
              }
            else
              for ($i=0; $i < count($bind_additional1) ; $i++) { 
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name[$i], $binding_val[$i]);
              }
          else
            if($bind_additional1)
              oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name,
 $binding_val,$bind_additional1,$bind_additional2);
            else
              oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name, $binding_val);
```

Comment: Why not using an array? Is there something wrong with array?

Comment: put than in your question, I can't read it

Comment: may be easier to write a class instead of correcting this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I wrote a function which generally performs all my requests.

```
function execSql($conn,$xsql,$sql_no,$return_val, $binding_val_name,$binding_val,$bind_additional1,$bind_additional2){
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $xsql);
    if($binding_val_name !=''){
      if(is_array($binding_val_name))
        foreach ($binding_val_name as $key => $value) {
          oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $key, $binding_val_name[$key]);
        }
      else if($bind_additional1)
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name, $binding_val,$bind_additional1,$bind_additional2);
      else
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $binding_val_name, $binding_val);
    }
    oci_execute($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
    if($return_val!='')
      oci_fetch_all($stmt,$result);

    $xsql = $xsql.' !!! sql_no:'.$sql_no.' return_val:'.$return_val.' binding_val_name:'./*(is_array($binding_val_name))?print_r($binding_val_name):*/$binding_val_name.' binding_val:'.$binding_val.' result:'.$result[$return_val][0];
    //echo /*' sql:'.$xsql.*/'!!! sql_no:'.$sql_no.' return_val:'.$return_val.' binding_val_name:'.$binding_val_name.' binding_val:'.$binding_val.' result:'.$result[$return_val][0];
    checkError($stmt,$sql_no.'. '.$xsql);
    oci_free_statement($stmt);

    if($return_val!=''&&$return_val!='1'||$return_val=='array')
      return (count($result)>1)?$result:$result[$return_val][0];
    if($binding_val_name!='')
      return $binding_val;
  }
```